# Use LINQ to compare two lists, and produce a third one with results from one OR the other

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, linq

I have two lists of elements that differ only on the `IsTemporalPaymentTerm` boolean field.

I want to use LINQ to compare the two lists, entry by entry, and produce a third list that has, for each entry, the one where `IsTemporalPaymentTerm = true`, and **if there isn't one**, then I want the one where `IsTemporalPaymentTerm = false`.

Here's some sample code:

```
var allResults = db.PaymentTerms
                       .AsQueryable()
                       .Where(y => y.WorkDate == date
                               && y.ProjectID == ProjectID 
                               && y.CompanyID == CompanyID
                               && y.PayeeID == PayeeID);

//TABLE WITH ONLY TEMPORAL PAYMENT TERMS
var onlyTemporalResults = allResults.Where(x => x.IsTemporalPaymentTerm);

//TABLE WITH ONLY NON-TEMPORAL PAYMENT TERMS
var nonTemporalResults = allResults.Where(x => !x.IsTemporalPaymentTerm);
```

So, basically what I want is to compare `onlyTemporalResults` against `nonTemporalResults` , and get a final list that has either the temporal payment term, **OR** the non-temporal payment term **if no temporal payment term could be found.**

Pseudo code example:

```
List<PaymentTerms> TemporalPaymentTerms = new List<PaymentTerms>();
PaymentTerm unnaprovedPT1 = new PaymentTerm  { PayeeID = 1, CompanyID = 2, ProjectID = 3, IsTemporalPaymentTerm = false };
PaymentTerm unnaprovedPT2 = new PaymentTerm  { PayeeID = 2, CompanyID = 2, ProjectID = 3, IsTemporalPaymentTerm = false };

TemporalPaymentTerms.Add(unnaprovedPT1); 
TemporalPaymentTerms.Add(unnaprovedPT2);  
   
List<PaymentTerms> NonTemporalPaymentTerms = new List<PaymentTerms>();
PaymentTerm approvedPT1 = new PaymentTerm  { PayeeID = 2, CompanyID = 2, ProjectID = 3, IsTemporalPaymentTerm = true};
PaymentTerm approvedPT1 = new PaymentTerm  { PayeeID = 3, CompanyID = 2, ProjectID = 3, IsTemporalPaymentTerm = true};

//LINQ query that merges both lists goes here.
    
//FINAL EXPECTED RESULT:
List<PaymentTerms> FinalList = [
{PayeeID = 1, CompanyID = 2, ProjectID = 3, IsTemporalPaymentTerm = false},
{PayeeID = 2, CompanyID = 2, ProjectID = 3, IsTemporalPaymentTerm = false},
{PayeeID = 3, CompanyID = 2, ProjectID = 3, IsTemporalPaymentTerm = true}
];
```

I know this can be done iterating over the two lists (temporal and non-temporal Payment Terms), and then comparing them, but I guess my question is:

Can this be done, more efficiently and in a more elegant way, using a single LINQ query? Maybe a certain form of join that I am missing? Conditional Where clauses?

So far I have failed to see the answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a lot of prose. Can you provide some code with it? Perhaps the classes you're working with?

Comment: @Llama I added some sample code with a brief description below, that I think makes things a little bit more clear.

Comment: @Llama also condensed the text to make the question less verbose.

Comment: That's a big improvement! :) Unfortunately I don't know the answer, but hopefully now your question is easier to digest someone will be able to provide an answer more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunPaymentTermsTest();
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void RunPaymentTermsTest()
{
    var temporalPaymentTerms = new List<PaymentTerm>
    {
        new PaymentTerm { PayeeID = 1, CompanyID = 2, ProjectID = 3, IsTemporalPaymentTerm = false },
        new PaymentTerm { PayeeID = 2, CompanyID = 2, ProjectID = 3, IsTemporalPaymentTerm = false }
    };

    var nonTemporalPaymentTerms = new List<PaymentTerm>()
    {
        new PaymentTerm { PayeeID = 2, CompanyID = 2, ProjectID = 3, IsTemporalPaymentTerm = true },
        new PaymentTerm { PayeeID = 3, CompanyID = 2, ProjectID = 3, IsTemporalPaymentTerm = true }
    };

    var toAdd = temporalPaymentTerms
        .Where(x =>
            !nonTemporalPaymentTerms.Any(y =>
                y.CompanyID == x.CompanyID &&
                y.PayeeID == x.PayeeID &&
                y.ProjectID == x.ProjectID))
        .ToList();

    var results = nonTemporalPaymentTerms;
    results.AddRange(toAdd);

    foreach (var result in results.OrderBy(x => x.PayeeID).ThenBy(x => x.CompanyID).ThenBy(x => x.ProjectID))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"PayeeID: {result.PayeeID}, CompanyID: {result.CompanyID}, ProjectID: {result.ProjectID}, IsTemporalPaymentTerm: {result.IsTemporalPaymentTerm}");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you very much!